# DataGridView selectrowand assign CurrentRow

Tags: c#

Once i fill DataGridView's Datasource property to my data i found first row is not selected by default, therefore i created following method and raise it once after grid is loaded. At the end you can see i've added: `grid.Rows[0].Selected` = true; because first row was not selected by default.

```
void InitializeGrid()
{
     grid.ReadOnly = true;
     grid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
     grid.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
     grid.MultiSelect = false;
     grid.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
     grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
     grid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

     if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)
     {
        grid.Rows[0].Selected = true;    //< ======= select first row
     }
}
```

This way my row is selected. Nevertheless `CurrentRow` is still null. How can i assign `SelectedRow as CurrentRow`?

I've tried below but CurrentRow has only `get;` property

```
if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      grid.Rows[0].Selected = true;
      grid.CurrentRow = grid.Rows[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow?view=netframework-4.8):

> ## Remarks
>
> To change the current row, you must set the CurrentCell property to a cell in the desired row.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i found solution:

```
if (grid.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    grid.Rows[0].Selected = true;
    grid.CurrentCell = grid.Rows[0].Cells[0];
}
```